# Can I read calendar events from "shared mailbox" users using the Office 365 API?

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps

I have some code set up which is successfully reading calendar events from full Office 365 user accounts

When I try and use the same code to read calendar events from a shared mailbox (after authenticating with that shared mailbox's email address and password), I get the following error...

> x-ms-diagnostics: 2000005;reason="The user account in the token is
>   disabled.";error_category="invalid_user"

Is is at all possible to read the calendar events from a "shared mailbox" account using the Office 365 API? Or can I only read calendar events from full user accounts?

Comment: It might help to post your code. I'm currently using EWS (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll) through Powershell to access mails in a shared mailbox. I haven't tried accessing calendar items. Can you see if your code works for mail items?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible although not the same as managing another users account. The tutorial for managing both the `Shared Inbox` and the `Calendar` can be found below:

> [Open and use a shared mailbox/calendar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-and-use-a-shared-mailbox-in-Outlook-Web-App-bc127866-42be-4de7-92ae-1ef2f787fd5c#__how_can_do)

It includes a brief video explanation and then step by step guide.

If this is for a small business then you can follow this guide instead:

> [shared mailboxes in Office 365 for Small Business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-shared-mailboxes-in-Office-365-for-Small-Business-ecacf5b0-b5c8-449f-a89a-b7e87dcb55d4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thanks Mark, my question was for accessing calendar events via the API rather then through Outlook or the Outlook web app through :)

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake, missed the capital API at the end. There are multiple API's you can use to access the calendar calls for what your trying to do. The latest is Microsoft Graph https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview. But it is a little vague about the functionality your looking for. When working on shared resources like a mail box and calendars then you may be more intrested in the Groups API http://dev.office.com/blogs/groupsrestapi

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [App-Only Permissions (Client Credentials Grant Flow)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365) ,the applications are quite powerful in terms of the data they can access within an Office 365 organization. Then you could use O365 API to access the shared mailbox resources. For example :try to use a GET https://outlook.office.com/api/{version}/me/calendars to get the actual calendar folders, then use the ID from the one you want to query to get specific calendar information.

Another choice is to use [EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj536567(v=exchg.150).aspx) to access shared mailbox information,  You could specify the Mailbox you want to access. If your shared Mailbox was called Shared@domain.com then code below is for your reference:

```
    FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,"Shared@domain.com")
    ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1000);
    service.FindItems(SharedMailbox,itemView);
```